# Can't start any service after installing iRedMail on CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, mysql, httpd, iredmail

I have attempted to install iRedMail on one of my servers.
After reboot, I can't start any service anymore.

```
[root@mx ~]# systemctl start httpd

** (pkttyagent:16323): WARNING **: Unable to register authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
Error registering authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files (g-dbus-error-quark, 2)
[root@mx ~]# systemctl start mysqld

** (pkttyagent:16348): WARNING **: Unable to register authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files
Error registering authentication agent: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.ServiceUnknown: The name org.freedesktop.PolicyKit1 was not provided by any .service files (g-dbus-error-quark, 2)
Failed to start mysqld.service: Unit mysqld.service failed to load: No such file or directory.
[root@mx ~]#
```

Does anyone know how to get this sorted out?

**Update**
Re-installing and starting polkit gave me this:

```
[root@mx ~]# systemctl start polkit
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Exhausted all available authentication mechanisms (tried: EXTERNAL, DBUS_COOKIE_SHA1, ANONYMOUS) (available: EXTERNAL, DBUS_COOKIE_SHA1, ANONYMOUS) (g-io-error-quark, 0)
Job for polkit.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status polkit.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@mx ~]# systemctl status polkit.service
● polkit.service - Authorization Manager
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/polkit.service; static; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-07-21 21:24:45 JST; 20s ago
     Docs: man:polkit(8)
  Process: 2478 ExecStart=/usr/lib/polkit-1/polkitd --no-debug (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 2478 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Jul 21 21:24:45 mx.076.wtf systemd[1]: Starting Authorization Manager...
Jul 21 21:24:45 mx.076.wtf systemd[1]: polkit.service: main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Jul 21 21:24:45 mx.076.wtf systemd[1]: Failed to start Authorization Manager.
Jul 21 21:24:45 mx.076.wtf systemd[1]: Unit polkit.service entered failed state.
Jul 21 21:24:45 mx.076.wtf systemd[1]: polkit.service failed.
```

Answer (score 0):

This kind of looks like something important got removed with the package installation.
the errors relate to policy kit.
Can you confirm that polkit and dbus are both still installed? `rpm -qi dbus`and `rpm -qi polkit`

logs may also contain information but seems here a policy is preventing the start of these services due to dbus not responding...because dbus is not installed or the policy kit is not responding via dbus.

Also possible SElinux is responsible...you can disable to test by editing:
`/etc/sysconfig/selinux` then logging out and back in.

If you find that selinux is responsible policies can be displayed with:
`getsebool -a | grep disable.*on`
and set like:
`setsebool httpd_disable_trans 1`

Comment: Both are still installed and SELinux is already disabled.
So it's not related to that.

Comment: Still this is surely an issue with polkit.. can you try : `yum reinstall polkit` and `systemctl start polkit` to see if it fixes the issue.

Comment: Just added the output I've got by doing so.

Comment: Can you confirm the status of dbus during your test `systemctl status dbus`  ?? it should be running.

Comment: Yes, it's running. However, I'm getting a series of messages next to it, like this one:

    Jul 22 02:22:23 mx.076.wtf dbus-daemon[630]: dbus[630]: [system] Rejected send message, 11 matched rules; type="error", sender=":1.2" (uid=0 pid=626 comm="") interface="(unset)" member="(unset)" error name="org.freede... pid=727 comm="")

Comment: So the process 626 (running as root) is unable to send messages via Dbus. However the posted error is cropped (org.freede???? ). So what we know is some process running as root has no permissions to make calls via dbus. I would try reinstalling dbus in order to try to correct any errors in permissions with `yum reinstall dbus`  however this is getting a little over my head.

Comment: Sadly, still no luck on this one. :( I'm afraid I'll just have to re-install the server, but I don't want to because I can't even dump MySQL databases because of that.

Comment: As root user you should be able to copy off the mysql data files (usually in /var/lib/mysql/) ... Sorry i have not been able to help fully resolve this. Good luck.