# MySqld Service wont start on Redhat7 after a yum update

Tags: linux, mysql, redhat, selinux

I'm having a problem with Redhat7 after a yum update.  Various services wont start and are giving permissions errors.

Similar problem to 
[Can't start any service after installing iRedMail on CentOS](https://serverfault.com/questions/790327/cant-start-any-service-after-installing-iredmail-on-centos)
but different OS, so maybe different problem.

Googling the error message brought me to the link above, so I tried some of the same fixes, see output of each below.  Please help!

---

```
service mysqld restart
```

Redirecting to /bin/systemctl restart mysqld.service
Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Exhausted all available authentication mechanisms (tried: EXTERNAL, DBUS_COOKIE_SHA1, ANONYMOUS) (available: EXTERNAL, DBUS_COOKIE_SHA1, ANONYMOUS) (g-io-error-quark, 0)
Job for mysqld.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status mysqld.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

---

the yum update that I performed yesterday included these packages:

```
grep "Mar 13.*" /var/log/yum.log  | awk '{ print $5 }' | grep policy
```

- selinux-policy-3.13.1-166.el7_4.9.noarch
- selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-166.el7_4.9.noarch

---

Tried reinstalling, but no change, also tried reinstalling the following, as well as the selinux policies above. (no joy)

- rpm -qi dbus
- rpm -qi polkit

---

```
systemctl status dbus
```

â dbus.service - D-Bus System Message Bus
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/dbus.service; static; vendor preset: disabled)
   Active: active (running) since Wed 2018-03-14 15:12:45 UTC; 47min ago
 Main PID: 677 (dbus-daemon)
   CGroup: /system.slice/dbus.service
           ââ677 /bin/dbus-daemon --system --address=systemd: --nofork --nopidfile --systemd-...

Mar 14 15:12:45 systemd[1]: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
Mar 14 15:12:45 systemd[1]: Starting D-Bus System Message Bus...
Mar 14 15:29:10 dbus-daemon[677]: dbus[677]: [system] Unable to reload config...ed
Mar 14 15:29:10 dbus-daemon[677]: Unable to reload configuration:  Failed to o...ed
Mar 14 15:29:10 dbus-daemon[677]: dbus[677]: [system] Unable to reload config...ed

```
journalctl -u dbus
```

Mar 14 15:12:45 systemd[1]: Started D-Bus System Message Bus.
Mar 14 15:12:45 systemd[1]: Starting D-Bus System Message Bus...
Mar 14 15:29:10 dbus-daemon[677]: dbus[677]: [system] Unable to reload configuration: Failed to open "/etc/dbus-1/system.conf": Permission denied
Mar 14 15:29:10 dbus-daemon[677]: Unable to reload configuration: Failed to open "/etc/dbus-1/system.conf": Permission denied

```
ls -l /etc/dbus-1/system.conf
```

-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 2991 Sep 12  2016 /etc/dbus-1/system.conf

---

```
systemctl start polkit
```

Error getting authority: Error initializing authority: Exhausted all available authentication mechanisms (tried: EXTERNAL, DBUS_COOKIE_SHA1, ANONYMOUS) (available: EXTERNAL, DBUS_COOKIE_SHA1, ANONYMOUS) (g-io-error-quark, 0)
Job for polkit.service failed because a timeout was exceeded. See "systemctl status polkit.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.

---

```
namei -l /etc/dbus-1/system.conf
```

f: /etc/dbus-1/system.conf
drwxr-xr-x root root /
drw------- root root etc
drwxr-xr-x root root dbus-1
-rwxr-xr-x root root system.conf

---

Additionally, here's the full list of things that got upgraded...
I'm thinking I should restore from backup...

- 1dhclient-4.2.5-58.el7_4.3.x86_64
- 1dhcp-common-4.2.5-58.el7_4.3.x86_64
- 1dhcp-libs-4.2.5-58.el7_4.3.x86_64
- 3bind-libs-9.9.4-51.el7_4.2.x86_64
- 3bind-libs-lite-9.9.4-51.el7_4.2.x86_64
- 3bind-license-9.9.4-51.el7_4.2.noarch
- 3bind-utils-9.9.4-51.el7_4.2.x86_64
- accountsservice-0.6.45-3.el7_4.1.x86_64
- accountsservice-libs-0.6.45-3.el7_4.1.x86_64
- apr-1.4.8-3.el7_4.1.x86_64
- at-3.1.13-22.el7_4.2.x86_64
- binutils-2.25.1-32.base.el7_4.2.x86_64
- colordiff-1.0.13-2.el7.noarch
- copy-jdk-configs-2.2-5.el7_4.noarch
- cryptsetup-1.7.4-3.el7_4.1.x86_64
- cryptsetup-libs-1.7.4-3.el7_4.1.x86_64
- cryptsetup-python-1.7.4-3.el7_4.1.x86_64
- curl-7.29.0-42.el7_4.1.x86_64
- device-mapper-multipath-0.4.9-111.el7_4.2.x86_64
- device-mapper-multipath-libs-0.4.9-111.el7_4.2.x86_64
- device-mapper-persistent-data-0.7.0-0.1.rc6.el7_4.1.x86_64
- dleyna-server-0.5.0-2.el7_4.x86_64
- dracut-033-502.el7_4.1.x86_64
- dracut-config-rescue-033-502.el7_4.1.x86_64
- dracut-network-033-502.el7_4.1.x86_64
- epel-release-7-11.noarch
- firefox-52.6.0-1.el7_4.x86_64
- gdb-7.6.1-100.el7_4.1.x86_64
- gdm-3.22.3-13.el7_4.x86_64
- glibc-2.17-196.el7_4.2.i686
- glibc-2.17-196.el7_4.2.x86_64
- glibc-common-2.17-196.el7_4.2.x86_64
- gtk3-3.22.10-5.el7_4.x86_64
- gtk3-immodule-xim-3.22.10-5.el7_4.x86_64
- gtk-update-icon-cache-3.22.10-5.el7_4.x86_64
- initscripts-9.49.39-1.el7_4.1.x86_64
- iptables-1.4.21-18.3.el7_4.x86_64
- iptables-services-1.4.21-18.3.el7_4.x86_64
- iwl1000-firmware-39.31.5.1-58.el7_4.noarch
- iwl100-firmware-39.31.5.1-58.el7_4.noarch
- iwl105-firmware-18.168.6.1-58.el7_4.noarch
- iwl135-firmware-18.168.6.1-58.el7_4.noarch
- iwl2000-firmware-18.168.6.1-58.el7_4.noarch
- iwl2030-firmware-18.168.6.1-58.el7_4.noarch
- iwl3160-firmware-22.0.7.0-58.el7_4.noarch
- iwl3945-firmware-15.32.2.9-58.el7_4.noarch
- iwl4965-firmware-228.61.2.24-58.el7_4.noarch
- iwl5000-firmware-8.83.5.1_1-58.el7_4.noarch
- iwl5150-firmware-8.24.2.2-58.el7_4.noarch
- iwl6000-firmware-9.221.4.1-58.el7_4.noarch
- iwl6000g2a-firmware-17.168.5.3-58.el7_4.noarch
- iwl6000g2b-firmware-17.168.5.2-58.el7_4.noarch
- iwl6050-firmware-41.28.5.1-58.el7_4.noarch
- iwl7260-firmware-22.0.7.0-58.el7_4.noarch
- java-1.7.0-openjdk-1.7.0.171-2.6.13.0.el7_4.x86_64
- java-1.7.0-openjdk-headless-1.7.0.171-2.6.13.0.el7_4.x86_64
- java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.161-0.b14.el7_4.x86_64
- java-1.8.0-openjdk-headless-1.8.0.161-0.b14.el7_4.x86_64
- kernel-3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
- kernel-tools-3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
- kernel-tools-libs-3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
- kmod-20-15.el7_4.7.x86_64
- kmod-libs-20-15.el7_4.7.x86_64
- kpartx-0.4.9-111.el7_4.2.x86_64
- kpatch-0.4.0-2.el7_4.noarch
- libblkid-2.23.2-43.el7_4.2.x86_64
- libcurl-7.29.0-42.el7_4.1.x86_64
- libdb-5.3.21-21.el7_4.i686
- libdb-5.3.21-21.el7_4.x86_64
- libdb-utils-5.3.21-21.el7_4.x86_64
- libgcc-4.8.5-16.el7_4.2.i686
- libgcc-4.8.5-16.el7_4.2.x86_64
- libgomp-4.8.5-16.el7_4.2.x86_64
- libgudev1-219-42.el7_4.10.x86_64
- liblouis-2.5.2-12.el7_4.x86_64
- liblouis-python-2.5.2-12.el7_4.noarch
- libmount-2.23.2-43.el7_4.2.x86_64
- libpciaccess-0.13.4-3.1.el7_4.x86_64
- libreswan-3.20-5.el7_4.x86_64
- libsmbclient-4.6.2-12.el7_4.x86_64
- libsss_idmap-1.15.2-50.el7_4.11.x86_64
- libsss_nss_idmap-1.15.2-50.el7_4.11.x86_64
- libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7_4.2.i686
- libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7_4.2.x86_64
- libstoragemgmt-1.4.0-5.el7_4.x86_64
- libstoragemgmt-python-1.4.0-5.el7_4.noarch
- libstoragemgmt-python-clibs-1.4.0-5.el7_4.x86_64
- libteam-1.25-6.el7_4.3.x86_64
- libtevent-0.9.31-2.el7_4.x86_64
- libuuid-2.23.2-43.el7_4.2.x86_64
- libvirt-client-3.2.0-14.el7_4.9.x86_64
- libvirt-daemon-3.2.0-14.el7_4.9.x86_64
- libvirt-daemon-config-network-3.2.0-14.el7_4.9.x86_64
- libvirt-daemon-driver-interface-3.2.0-14.el7_4.9.x86_64
- libvirt-daemon-driver-network-3.2.0-14.el7_4.9.x86_64
- libvirt-daemon-driver-nodedev-3.2.0-14.el7_4.9.x86_64
- libvirt-daemon-driver-nwfilter-3.2.0-14.el7_4.9.x86_64
- libvirt-daemon-driver-qemu-3.2.0-14.el7_4.9.x86_64
- libvirt-daemon-driver-secret-3.2.0-14.el7_4.9.x86_64
- libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-3.2.0-14.el7_4.9.x86_64
- libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-core-3.2.0-14.el7_4.9.x86_64
- libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-disk-3.2.0-14.el7_4.9.x86_64
- libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-gluster-3.2.0-14.el7_4.9.x86_64
- libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-iscsi-3.2.0-14.el7_4.9.x86_64
- libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-logical-3.2.0-14.el7_4.9.x86_64
- libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-mpath-3.2.0-14.el7_4.9.x86_64
- libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-rbd-3.2.0-14.el7_4.9.x86_64
- libvirt-daemon-driver-storage-scsi-3.2.0-14.el7_4.9.x86_64
- libvirt-daemon-kvm-3.2.0-14.el7_4.9.x86_64
- libvirt-libs-3.2.0-14.el7_4.9.x86_64
- libwbclient-4.6.2-12.el7_4.x86_64
- linux-firmware-20170606-58.gitc990aae.el7_4.noarch
- microcode_ctl-2.1-22.5.el7_4.x86_64
- mutter-3.22.3-12.el7_4.x86_64
- mysql-community-client-5.7.21-1.el7.x86_64
- mysql-community-common-5.7.21-1.el7.x86_64
- mysql-community-libs-5.7.21-1.el7.x86_64
- mysql-community-libs-compat-5.7.21-1.el7.x86_64
- mysql-community-server-5.7.21-1.el7.x86_64
- nautilus-3.22.3-4.el7_4.x86_64
- nautilus-extensions-3.22.3-4.el7_4.x86_64
- net-snmp-libs-5.7.2-28.el7_4.1.x86_64
- nfs-utils-1.3.0-0.48.el7_4.2.x86_64
- python-dmidecode-3.12.2-1.1.el7.x86_64
- python-gobject-3.22.0-1.el7_4.1.x86_64
- python-gobject-base-3.22.0-1.el7_4.1.x86_64
- python-perf-3.10.0-693.21.1.el7.x86_64
- qemu-img-1.5.3-141.el7_4.6.x86_64
- qemu-kvm-1.5.3-141.el7_4.6.x86_64
- qemu-kvm-common-1.5.3-141.el7_4.6.x86_64
- rhnsd-5.0.13-7.3.el7_4.x86_64
- samba-client-libs-4.6.2-12.el7_4.x86_64
- samba-common-4.6.2-12.el7_4.noarch
- samba-common-libs-4.6.2-12.el7_4.x86_64
- samba-common-tools-4.6.2-12.el7_4.x86_64
- samba-libs-4.6.2-12.el7_4.x86_64
- selinux-policy-3.13.1-166.el7_4.9.noarch
- selinux-policy-targeted-3.13.1-166.el7_4.9.noarch
- sos-3.4-13.el7_4.noarch
- spice-glib-0.33-6.el7_4.1.x86_64
- spice-gtk3-0.33-6.el7_4.1.x86_64
- sssd-client-1.15.2-50.el7_4.11.x86_64
- swiagent-1.8.0.551-835342.x86_64
- systemd-219-42.el7_4.10.x86_64
- systemd-libs-219-42.el7_4.10.i686
- systemd-libs-219-42.el7_4.10.x86_64
- systemd-python-219-42.el7_4.10.x86_64
- systemd-sysv-219-42.el7_4.10.x86_64
- systemtap-runtime-3.1-5.el7_4.x86_64
- teamd-1.25-6.el7_4.3.x86_64
- tigervnc-license-1.8.0-2.el7_4.noarch
- tigervnc-server-minimal-1.8.0-2.el7_4.x86_64
- tuned-2.8.0-5.el7_4.2.noarch
- tzdata-2018c-1.el7.noarch
- tzdata-java-2018c-1.el7.noarch
- util-linux-2.23.2-43.el7_4.2.x86_64
- webkitgtk4-2.14.7-3.el7.x86_64
- webkitgtk4-jsc-2.14.7-3.el7.x86_64
- webkitgtk4-plugin-process-gtk2-2.14.7-3.el7.x86_64
- xorg-x11-server-common-1.19.3-11.el7_4.2.x86_64
- xorg-x11-server-Xorg-1.19.3-11.el7_4.2.x86_64

Comment: You need to look at the error messages that dbus is logging.

Comment: added journalctl dbus command above

Comment: Interesting. What are the permissions on the containing directories? Try `namei -l /etc/dbus-1/system.conf` And you may as well re-enable SELinux too. That probably isn't the problem.

Comment: namei -l /etc/dbus-1/system.conf  

f: /etc/dbus-1/system.conf  
drwxr-xr-x root root /  
drw------- root root etc  
drwxr-xr-x root root dbus-1  
-rwxr-xr-x root root system.conf

Comment: Yeah, someone or something utterly broke the permissions of `/etc`. See user460788's answer.

Answer (score 1):

> drw------- root root etc

That doesn't look correct, /etc should be `drwxr-xr-x` so

```
# chmod 755 /etc
```

will fix that and may fix the wider issue.

Comment: This is correct. In order to access a file, you have to have permissions to the file, and also to read and traverse all of its parent directories.